# How to run jasmine tests written in typescript for node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, jasmine

I am interested to test my express application written in typescript.
Basically I am using jasmine (to write test cases), webpack (to bundle ts to js) and karma (test runner)

Please find the files

```
// about.service.ts - code to be tested
import { MongoClient, MongoError, Collection, ObjectId } from 'mongodb';

export class AboutService { // functionality }

// about.service.spec.ts - test cases
import { AboutService} from 'about.service.ts';

describe('services.about.service.spec', () => {
   it('should_return_null_date', () => {
       // test cases here
   });
});

// karma.conf.js - karma configuration file
var webpackConfig = require('./karma.webpack');

module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
        require('karma-jasmine'),
        require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
        require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
        require('karma-webpack')
    ],
    files: [
        'somefiles'
    ],
    mime: {
        'text/x-typescript': ['ts']
    },
    preprocessors: {
        'somefiles': ['webpack']
    },
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    reporters: ['kjhtml'],
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    client: {
        clearContext: false,
        captureConsole: false
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_WARN,
    autoWatch: true,
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
 });
}

// karma.webpack.js
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
module.exports = {
    resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js'], },
    module: {
      rules: [{
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: ['awesome-typescript-loader']
      }]
    },
    target: "node",
    externals: [nodeExternals()]
 }
```

Webpack has ended compilation success but when karma launches in chrome. It says `require('mongodb'); not found`, I guess require is not available in browser.

All I would like to know how do I run my tests in node environment rather than browser? Are there any karma loaders? I would like to write tests in jasmine itself and I need webpack to convert ts to js. All I want is a test runner something like karma which runs in node than browser?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project currently uses not just Jasmine but Karma. Karma runner is supposed to run tests in browsers, it isn't suited to run purely in Node.js.

Tests need to be run with [Jasmine runner](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm) directly. Node projects usually don't need Webpack, TypeScript files should be compiled with `target: 'es6'` and `module: 'commonjs'` options.

There are options to avoid TypeScript compilation step with third-party packages like [`jasmine-ts`](https://github.com/svi3c/jasmine-ts).

Another option is to switch to testing framework and runner that have improved support for preprocessors and thus, TypeScript in Node.js tests - which Jest is.

Comment: Thanks, so should i directly run using jasmine runner but I think i need a compilation phase from ts to js right?

Comment: Yeah. Or use jasmine-ts to skip compilation, it uses ts-node to run Jasmine. In 2018, I'd personally go with Jest. Its module-mocking features are indispensable in Node.

Comment: Great. It works. I think moq.ts is a great framework for mocking typescript. dont you think so?

Comment: I'm not sure how well it plays with real-world scenarios. It looks a bit strange because stubs, mocks and spies are inseparable, and it doesn't cover spies. Also doesn't have the support from testing frameworks, so it cannot be integrated with their assertions - that's a problem with smaller libs. But thanks, I'll take a closer look at it.